Failed to Convert APK to AAB Using bundletool: Unrecognized Flags
I'm trying to use bundletool to convert an APK file to an Android App Bundle (AAB), but I'm encountering an issue specifying the keystore path, password, key alias, and key password. When I attempt to execute the command, the flags --ks, --ks-pass, --ks-key-alias, and --key-pass are being rejected as unrecognized. Is there a correct way to specify these flags? How can I overcome this issue to successfully convert the APK file to AAB using bundletool?
I tried to use bundletool to convert an APK file to an Android App Bundle (AAB) using the specified command with the required flags for keystore path, password, key alias, and key password. However, when executing the command, bundletool is rejecting these flags as unrecognized. I expected the command to run successfully and generate the AAB file without any errors.

Please update your question and include the full command you execute (replace the used password with a dummy password).
